# Android studio could not resolve Firebase messaging

Tags: android

Unable to build gradle file. Getting error : Failed to resolve Firebase- Messaging

I have tried several solutions but none of them as mentioned below working:
- Clean and rebuild project
- Invalidate caches and restart
- Updated Android repository and Google play services
- Updated gradle version

Below is my code for gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.flexyn"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.0"
        flavorDimensions "default"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"http://flexyn.projectdevelopment.co/"'
        }

        debug{
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"

            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"http://flexyn.projectdevelopment.co/"'
        }

        productionTest {
            initWith release
            debuggable true
        }

        innerTest {
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
   // implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.percolate:caffeine:0.3.3'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.13.0'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.+'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.1'
    implementation project(':datetimepicker')
    implementation project(':swipelayout')
    implementation project(':cameraview')
    implementation project(':pinentryedittext')
    implementation project(':universalvideoview')
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    implementation project(':sample-core')
    implementation "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:$rootProject.qbSdkVersion"
    implementation "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:$rootProject.qbSdkVersion"
    implementation "com.quickblox:chat-message-adapter:$rootProject.qbChatAdapterVersion"
    implementation("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat-extensions:$qbSdkVersion")
    implementation "com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview:library:$rootProject.stickylistheadersVersion@aar"
    implementation "com.github.orangegangsters:swipy:$rootProject.swipyVersion@aar"
    implementation "se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'

}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Below is my code for top level gradle file:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.8.1'
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    minSdkVersion = 14
    targetSdkVersion = 27
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    lintAbortOnError = false
    // QuickBlox SDK version
    qbChatAdapterVersion = '2.0'
    qbSdkVersion = '3.8.1'
    versionCode = 381
    versionName = '3.8.1'
    testRunnerVersion = "0.4.1"
    // Dependency versions
    playServicesVersion = '11.4.2'
    supportLibVersion = '27.1.1'
    supportV4Version = supportLibVersion
    appcompatV7Version = supportLibVersion
    recyclerviewV7Version = supportLibVersion
    supportAnnotationsVersion = supportLibVersion
    designVersion = supportLibVersion
    cardViewVersion = supportLibVersion
    glideVersion = '3.6.1'
    pullToRefreshVersion = '3.2.3'
    robotoTextViewVersion = '4.0.0'
    stickylistheadersVersion = '0.4.2'
    swipyVersion = '1.2.3'
    dimensionDefault = 'default'
}
```

Comment: thank you, Priyanka for accepting my answer i hope it will helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this thing into Gradle file into app gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
```

And put this file into main gradle:

```
    buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

It works for me, maybe work for you also.

Comment: I didn't found ***compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'*** this line into your app build.gradle  dependencies.

Comment: This is also added.

 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

Comment: Go to ***tools-->android-->sync project with gradle files*** try this may be this will work ,if you put all this things than i think it will have to work.

Comment: Tried this also multiple times. No Luck!

Comment: It is working but with older version of firebase messaging:12.0.1. Getting error with latest version.